# inlining CSS issues

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my CSS inline, but this gives me some issues. I'm using font-awesome, and I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

in the CSS. So when this is inlined, it doesn't work (I see no icons on the page). Does this mean that I can't do this inline?

Additional information:

html:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.icon-wrench:before {
  content: "\f0ad";
}
</style>

<i class="icon-wrench"></i>
```

It displayed correctly when I was linking to the stylesheet like this:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But not, it seems with the method described above.

Comment: provide a link for the issue.

Comment: "inline" as in `style=""` or `<style>...</style>` ?

Comment: as in <style type="text/css"></style>. I'm afraid I don't have a link as it's on my local machine.

Comment: Yup, same question as Alex. You can place that code on the page inside `style` tags, but not inside a style attribute on an element—which is an inefficient way to implement CSS anyway.

Comment: This isn't enough information to work with. What elements are you displaying inline? Please post your HTML and CSS markup that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Have you made sure the path to the font files is correct? Remember that paths in an external stylesheet are relative to that stylesheet's location, whereas in `<style>` the path will be treated as relative to the HTML document's location.

Comment: OK, have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I use this and it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the path to the font files is correct?

Remember that paths in an external stylesheet are relative to that stylesheet's location, whereas in `<style>` the path will be treated as relative to the HTML document's location.